# Error in calculating standard error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I have calculated the mean of the observations for each treatment using

```
Data %>% group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Nitrogen, na.rm = TRUE))
```

I have got a single value for each treatment. Now I want to calculate the standard deviation and standard error of the mean. For which I have used,

```
Data %>% group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>% summarise_each(funs = mean, sd, se=sd(.)/sqrt(n()), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But it gives an error. I am not sure what is my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`summarise_each` is getting deprecated and `funs` is replaced by `list`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
   group_by(Treatment) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                       sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                       se=~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))
```

If we are not sure about the column types, check

```
str(Data)
```

and apply the functions only on the numeric columns.  Without changing much in the previous code, replace the `summarise_at` to `summarise_if` for numeric columns

```
 Data %>%
   group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                       sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                       se=~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))
```

If some columns have `class` `factor` and needs to be used for the `mean/sd`, then first convert those column/columns to `numeric` with `as.numeric(as.character(Data[[yourcolumn]]))`

It can be reproduced with `iris` data

```
data(iris)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                        sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                        se=~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())))
# A tibble: 3 x 13
#  Species Sepal.Length_me… Sepal.Width_mean Petal.Length_me… Petal.Width_mean Sepal.Length_sd Sepal.Width_sd Petal.Length_sd
#  <fct>              <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>
#1 setosa              5.01             3.43             1.46            0.246           0.352          0.379           0.174
#2 versic…             5.94             2.77             4.26            1.33            0.516          0.314           0.470
#3 virgin…             6.59             2.97             5.55            2.03            0.636          0.322           0.552
# … with 5 more variables: Petal.Width_sd <dbl>, Sepal.Length_se <dbl>, Sepal.Width_se <dbl>, Petal.Length_se <dbl>,
#   Petal.Width_se <dbl>
```

---

In the OP's post, some of the functions have anonymous function and `na.rm = TRUE` seems to be from the `mean` (not clear).

Comment: @akrun, It worked for one dataset but for another one, it gives the error: Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

Comment: @Jessica That is because `mean/sd` etc works on numeric columns.  If it is character/factor variable, it needs to be first converted to `numeric` by `as.numeric(as.character(columnname))` Please check the `str(Data)`

Comment: @akrun, I got it, thank you! But I got two mean values for each of the treatment for each Rep. Can I get one value after averaging across the Reps as I want to use the mean value to make a plot.

Comment: @Jessica I think you need to remove `Rep` from the group_by `group_by(Treatment, Rep)` to `group_by(Treatment)`

Comment: @akrun, I tried it but still gives an error with ggplot.

Comment: @Jessica As you haven't provided any reproducible example with `dput`, it is not clear.  I showed the code with  a reproducible example

Comment: @akrun, I have a large data so I have pasted first ten lines after getting mean, sd and se using both Treatment and Rep with group_by.